# How to remember and highlight selected drawer items using ListTile in the flutter application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have a flutter app with a simple navigation drawer that corresponds to different routes on being clicked. I want to highlight the selected item on the drawer on being clicked/tapped. How can i achieve this? Is there any lucid way to achieve this functionality without changing the base code?
Any help will be appreciated.

Here's the code for the Navigation drawer.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sbox_admin/api/shared_service.dart';

class NavList extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavList({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.70, //70% of the screen
        child: Column(
          // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('images/redAccent.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )),
                    arrowColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[700],
                    accountName: Text(''),
                    accountEmail: Text(
                      'username@gmail.com',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 22.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[700],
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/profile.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    hoverColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    title: Text(
                      'Sellers',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                    },
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 1.0,
                    // color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    hoverColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    title: Text(
                      'Shops',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.shop),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.popUntil(
                          context,
                          ModalRoute.withName('/home'),
                        );
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/shops');
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.popUntil(
                        context,
                        ModalRoute.withName('/home'),
                      );
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/shops');
                    },
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 1.0,
                    // color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    hoverColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    title: Text(
                      'Orders',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.popUntil(
                          context,
                          ModalRoute.withName('/home'),
                        );
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/orders');
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Navigator.popUntil(
                        context,
                        ModalRoute.withName('/home'),
                      );
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/orders');
                    },
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 1.0,
                    // color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    hoverColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    title: Text(
                      'Logout',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        SharedService.logout().then(
                          (_) => Navigator.of(context)
                              .pushReplacementNamed('/login'),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      SharedService.logout().then(
                        (_) => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/login'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 1.0,
                    // color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Version 1.0.1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter : How to remember and highlight selected drawer item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620530/flutter-how-to-remember-and-highlight-selected-drawer-item)

Comment: No. It didn't . If you can provide a solution for my code, that would help.